# Как расшифровать файл

Tags: php

Есть зашифрованный php файл. Вот содержимое.

```
5a65 6e64 000b 3230 3034 3037 3232 3033
0002 3300 0438 3231 0005 3139 3637 0078
f90d 0a9f 320c 8d57 cd6a 1351 143e 0611
6d36 7d01 212f d024 73e7 2737 5a05 29b1
16b4 4869 a5a8 1042 67da 0c24 3365 66aa
75d9 8a50 7051 7021 76e3 13b8 a8a2 5885
b8d0 a59b 19d0 455f a062 9f40 10c1 73ff
2633 9304 8509 13e6 9c7b cebd df3d 3fdf
61c5 ffae e3d9 9596 c71a 4d80 cdd4 edf4
c4d1 c4e9 cb9a a969 5add a298 4165 adae
5bc4 b49a 5850 3821 b0b7 fafd 47d5 8e6d
07cc b805 5da7 8346 50ad 4eeb 0457 11de
6c43 270c 5ddf 6b87 5127 88a6 28b5 8861
3488 c5a3 4d6e 09cd 1916 ff31 0d0a 4920
2ad4 ce0b 8689 5b68 98dc 8b6c 2fa7 2948
e754 239d c332 e378 d10c eb9e 972a 91b3
1dd5 58ed ba5c 59eb b2bb 8bae ac2c 5f9f
a1f2 b679 0ee2 ca32 27a3 5aa1 4ef3 e313
f89e 0d0a 357e 9654 8a2f 1dbe 48a9 da02
5680 6ab5 c69b 6975 b3bb 29f9 8fc4 7cb5
2478 717e db18 570b 8bb7 5796 b992 097b
25c1 9a0b 4a38 38b4 96ee b496 a4d6 7e49
f170 43bc ccd4 8f09 2769 f7d0 256b d432
d283 026a 94c2 6c57 bb1a bf4c f6e2 a3f8
75fc 313e ac24 8f93 9d64 373e 8c07 f1a7
f80d 7e3a aa24 3bf8 f75d fc16 7506 f81e
c447 c93e 7eac e08a c3f8 3dca 3e54 50c8
560c 92a7 c993 d91a dacc 6265 c1bd d471
a140 081e d184 af45 3075 06e6 9aef adbb
1b45 3429 fc18 8fa6 05ad c5f9 85c5 9624
bbcf f240 292d 0d0a 8c51 31a3 524f 93e3
89c2 2ce3 aa09 c767 585a e133 7273 2ba1
1384 4cc2 30de 9543 4daa 2d67 5c71 3e6d
245e 317f c2ad 4d27 78e0 867e 908d 49a6
5c96 1b1a 0d4a 263d 90d2 e992 6074 d2b3
f274 2ca7 2c25 ce84 a71b b67b fec6 8663
b75d 4fb1 ebd3 b3e3 662c 257d 9e76 1596
cd14 8fa5 e7e4 121d 1d8a c7d3 e19a dd77
bd36 4bca c0ef 0998 7406 1319 c2a4 b339
c41a dad3 e1d7 8474 14d2 9294 4e73 242c
354f 2af1 bcac d94a acae ca80 b0eb 3f54
0cfc a22c dee3 5c18 a0a7 e459 2723 6213
6ec8 923f 026e 1d10 593c efba 1ff4 15d5
de95 ed7d 9c27 0b7e 0d0a 0c46 8258 87d5
5b37 055e 143e 0ff9 5e2e 861b 60fb 7d12
4681 b046 e1d5 ff58 3b9e 60ad 0951 d0f1
c2e1 de29 fc4e edf0 3606 f910 a5ac 9e69
ffc8 40a6 763f 3ff6 a570 99b0 1df6 6a1d
1e22 ae67 3bdb 6ac1 b722 fb25 39b7 7ff2
2d37 8554 44e7 7296 03d1 74cf f2f4 e509
6b85 e593 e2da cc65 d14c fa4e a85f 2fce
8f37 2ea4 b26d d7f3 0f61 3bdb c22a 3245
1a0d ecb4 4693 7f59 8b82 de14 314d 6a1a
54cb e8ff 052d 671d 2e
```

Его можно как-то расшифровать?

Comment: Каждые два символа - шестнадцетиричный код символа. Начинается там с Zend... Дальше вы уж как-нибудь сами.

Comment: а дальше шляпа какая то бинарная :)